# After how long do votes get locked?

Tags: support

After a certain period of time, one can not change their votes on a specific post unless it is edited. How long does it take for the vote to get locked?

Comment: See [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213)

Answer (score 1):

5 minutes from the time of your initial vote.

In other words, you can change your vote as many times as you want within that initial 5 minutes. Changing your vote does not reset the timer.